# fingerprintjs fingerprint.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fingerprint

currently I'm struggling with fingerprint in my previous project i solved this in this way:

```
 const test = async (req, res, next) => {
    // other code   
    
    const FingerprintJS = require('@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs');
    const store = require('store')

    FingerprintJS.get({
      preprocessor: function(key, value) {
          return value
      }
    },function(components){
        let values = components.map(function (component) { return component.value });
        let device_id = FingerprintJS.x64hash128(values.join(''), 31);
        store.set('print', { device: device_id })
    });

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    
    // other code
    
  };
```

But now I cant set it up to work.. I'm getting error in console.log :

```
(node:4940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: FingerprintJS.get is not a function
    at login (C:\Users\PC06\Desktop\project\backend\controllers\clients-controllers.js:53:17)
(node:4940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
non-zero exit code.
```

Any help for this?